# PHP print message

Tags: php

i want to print a message from php code, when the user clicks on button. I added code in php, and placed and if condition that executes when the user clicks on the button.
Here's the code of default.php:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
echo '<b>Ok.</b>';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP3</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>


<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="default.php">
  <p>
    <label for="textfield1">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="textfield2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Submit"  />
    <br />
    <br />
  <label id="label1">
  </label></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

"Ok" should be printed.
But i see no "Ok" message get printed.

What can i do?
Thanks

Comment: is this code in `default.php`?

Comment: Does it work if you replace your action with `action="#"`

Comment: The code is in default.php. If i replace the action with action="#" i have the same result.

Comment: possibly your server doesnt know how to process php. look at the source code and see if you have anything.

Comment: Im confused. When you say look at the source code, do you mean like when running the website in internet explorer--view...source? if yes, then yes, i can see the php code there too.

Comment: it means php isn't installed at all or isn't installed properly. Have you installed php? What is address of the page you are working on? Is it something like http://localhost/default.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're just testing your PHP file locally then try installing [XAMMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) to test your php file again, if it works then PHP wasn't installed before. XAMMP includes PHP, MySQL and Apache.

Comment: It seems the download for XAMMP is unavailable at the moment. lol what a luck. Edit: ok, downloading now.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in your body tag ? It should confirm if php is installed on your server.

Edit, just saw your last message, if your server is not running PHP, then you have to install it to achieve the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you should submit the form to itself or leave it blank. Check the form action and make sure you are posting to right php file.

Comment: Im posting in the right php file. There is only one php file(default.php).     What do you mean with submit the form to itself?

Comment: o ok. Yes, im submiting the form to itself, but still im getting nothing.       What can i do?

Comment: look at the source code. see if it you see php code but if your server is not processing your php code.

Comment: I can see the php code. But if my server is not processing it, how could i solve this?. Im using Apache.

Comment: that figures. apache doesnt know about php. make sure, php is installed and configured properly. I cant really guess. but check out adding php to apache.

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing "Ok" before the DOCTYPE declaration -- it may be that it's there and you're not seeing it in the browser.  Have you tried viewing the source and making sure your "Ok" isn't really there?

You might want to move your php code into the body part of your document.

Comment: I have moved it just now. Just after the body tag. But the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

If you say you can't see the PHP code when you click view source in your web browser you don't have PHP installed on your server. You need PHP to run this script. You would need to get in touch with your web host or enable it on your web server if its your own.

Comment: I can see the PHP code when i click view source on my web browser.