# Not sure how to echo out the Selected data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sanitization

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `nameData` FROM `accountsDone` WHERE `nameToSearch` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
    echo "Exists";
}
```

Instead of echoing out `Exists`, I want it to echo out `nameData`. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: How many rows it's intended to return?

Comment: Just 1 row :) @YourCommonSense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP print message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559626/php-print-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want **only one row** then append `LIMIT 1` to your `SELECT` query, like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `nameData` FROM `accountsDone` WHERE `nameToSearch` = ? LIMIT 1");
```

So there are two approaches to display `nameData`:

**Method(1):**

First bind the variable `$nameData` to the prepared statement, and then fetch the result into this bound variable.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `nameData` FROM `accountsDone` WHERE `nameToSearch` = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows){
    $stmt->bind_result($nameData);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo $nameData;
}else{
    echo "No result found";
}
```

**Method(2):**

First use `get_result()` method to get the result set from the prepared statement, and then use `fetch_array` to fetch the result row from the result set.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `nameData` FROM `accountsDone` WHERE `nameToSearch` = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows){
    $row = $result->fetch_array()
    echo $row['nameData'];
}else{
    echo "No result found";
}
```

Comment: I see you removed the `> 0` from the `if($stmt->num_rows)` Why is that?

Comment: @ILovephp123 `if($stmt->num_rows > 0){...` and `if($stmt->num_rows){...` is pretty much the same thing, you can choose either one. It just checks whether the `SELECT` query returns any row or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can  below code i hope your query is working fine it returns result properly then you can use below code.

```
$stmt->bind_result($nameData);
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                printf ("%s\n", $nameData);
            }
```

Comment: But what if I want it in echo terms? Would `echo $nameData;` be fine?

Comment: ya you can also use  echo  $nameData;

Answer (score 0):

Note that `affected_rows` won't do anything useful here.
However, nor you don't need `num_rows` as well (and therefore store_result too)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `nameData` FROM `accountsDone` WHERE `nameToSearch` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($nameData);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $nameData;
```

Considering all that hassle, even without useless functions, you may find PDO a way better approach:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `nameData` FROM `accountsDone` WHERE `nameToSearch` = ?");
$stmt->execute($query);
echo->$stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: And what if nothing exists for what the MYSQL statement is trying to do?

Comment: then, nothing will be echoed.